# How can I get rid from feet pain?

Tags: pain, foot-pain, feet

After a hard day sometimes, I feel pain in my feet . Specially in night I feel that my feet are suffer a strange pain. How can I get rid from this pain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. What I always do before going to sleep is a light feet massage with oil. It helps relax the muscles and relieves pain. Besides, when I sleep, I always put a pillow under my feet, which helps incredibly. Feet excercise like walking on your toes, bending feet, also helps. 
Also make sure the shoes you wear during the day are feet-friendly (no flats, slippers, high heels).